# How can I make a realtime notification system in Zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to implement real time notification system with PHP which runs on a shared server. It may be build by socket.io or Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can user ZendService GCM to Zend 2.

Example:

Create your Class to manager Push

```
use Useful\Controller\ControlController;
use ZendService\Google\Gcm\Client;
use ZendService\Google\Gcm\Message;
use ZendService\Apple\Apns\Message\Alert;
use ZendService\Google\Exception\RuntimeException;

class PushNotificationController {
   const SERVER_KEY = "YOUR FIREBASE SERVER KEY";
}
```

Add the function to Send

```
public function sendGoogleMessage($registatoin_ids, $data) {
    try {
        $key = SERVER_KEY ;
        $Google = new \ZendService\Google\Gcm\Client ();
        $Google->setApiKey ( $key );

        $Message = new \ZendService\Google\Gcm\Message ();          
        $Message->setData ( $data );

        // up to 100 registration ids can be sent to at once
        $Message->setRegistrationIds ( $registatoin_ids );
        $Message->setDelayWhileIdle ( false );
        $Message->setTimeToLive ( 600 );
    } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
        return false;
    }
    // Envio
    try {
        $Response = $Google->send ( $Message );
    } catch ( RuntimeException $e ) {
        echo $e->getMessage () . PHP_EOL;
        exit ( 1 );
    }

    return array (
            "Successful" => $Response->getSuccessCount (),
            "Failures" => $Response->getFailureCount (),
            "Canonicals" => $Response->getCanonicalCount () 
    );
}
```

[ZendService\Google\Gcm — Zend Framework 2 2.4.9 documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zendservice.google.gcm.html)